# Programming reoccurring daily, weekly and monthly events through a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, scheduled-tasks, rake-task

I need some help figuring out how to program reoccurring (*Daily, Weekly* and *Monthly*) events in my rails app. 
I am planning on using a **rake task** and also the [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) to do my scheduling jobs in production.

I have looked into gems like [ice_cube gem](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube) as well as other gems that extend the ice_cube gem but all seem to be over complicated for what I want to accomplished.

I am only interested in showing a daily feed that shows events only happening on that day.

But I do what to give users the ability to create *Daily, Weekly*, and *Monthly* events and never have to manually enter or update these events.

This is where I am struggling at the moment.

My Event model has the following relevant fields.

```
t.datetime "event_start_time"
t.datetime "event_end_time"
t.string   "event_frequency"
t.datetime "event_signup_time"
```

In my view that creates events I have the following UI[image]

At at a very high level in my rake task called it `event_scheduler.rake` under lib/tasks, I want to query my Event model, get all events and determine whether an event happens *Daily, Weekly* or *Monthly* and update the following fields accordingly:

```
event_start_time
event_end_time
event_signup_time
```

I can also have a switch statement to check for *Daily, Weekly*, and *Monthly*.

This still looks complicated to me. If anybody can suggest a piece of code, an alternative or different approach I'll appreciate it very much.

Comment: I would do this by running a single rake task once every day, (via the scheduler), and have this rake task in turn call a class method in the Event model, which looks at all the relevant data and decides which, if any, events need to be created.  Keep the actual scheduling as simple as possible, and let your class do all the logic.

Comment: I'm guessing that in your schema there is a class which is "above" events, and that this is what people are actually editing?  Eg ScheduledEvent, which could be set to recur monthly, and then that has a bunch of Events associated with it, each of which have a specific time etc.

Comment: All the editing happens in my Event model. And at the moment  I don't have a class that is "above" Events. Could you elaborate a little more on how the ScheduledEvent would work. I am guessing this is where I could store the `event_frequency` field which stores id to Events happening daily, weekly and monthly? Is this somewhat close to what you are suggesting?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Imagine when you go to put a recurring event in google calendar or something.  There is the concept of the "recurring event" and then the actual events which are generated from that, as children.